# Why doesn't std::cout display correctly?

Tags: c++, cout

I recently coded a simple C++ program which solves quadratic equations.

I'm sure you're familiar with quadratic equations : ax^2 + bx + c

And i tried to solve it using Delta method.

Here's the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

inline void Seprator()
{
    cout << endl << "---------------------------------------";
}
inline void endline()
{
    cout << endl;
}

double a,b,c;

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to AMR Quadratic Equation Solver Program.";
    endline();
    cout << "All development process by Amirreza Hashemieh - amrapps@outlook.com";
    endline();
    cout << "Standard form of Quadratic Equation : ax^2 + bx + c";
    endline();
    cout << "To exit the program,simply close the window.";
    Seprator();
    Seprator();
    Seprator();
    endline();

    while(true)
    {
        cout << "Enter a > press enter > Enter b > press enter > Enter c "
                "> press enter :";
        endline();
        cin >> a >> b >> c;

        double delta = (b*b) - (4*a*c);

        if (delta < 0)
            cout << "No Answer!!! ";
        else if(delta == 0)
            cout << (-b) / (2*a);
        else
            cout << "Answer 1 : " << cout << (-b+sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
        endline();
        cout << "   Answer 2 : " << cout << (-b-sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);


        Seprator();
        endline();
    }
}
```

It works fine but it displays some mess before the answer!

for example set a to 4 and b to 12 and c to 5. It should display -0.5 and -2.5 for answers.It does this but some mess data before the actual answer is shown.(i don't know what they are?)

Comment: Ok, so where are the code and the mess? Post the code here; don't link it from somewhere else.

Comment: @FredLarson it displays 0x601608-0.5 instead of -0.5 and 0x601608-2.5 instead of -2.5 !!!

Comment: As a side-note, avoid using `std::endl` unless you *really* need to flush the output-stream. Also, your two functions seem rather useless, define some `const char[]` instead and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `cout` in here:

```
cout << "Answer 1 : " << cout << (-b+sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
```

That's putting a pointer value in your stream, which prints as hexadecimal. Just get rid of it:

```
cout << "Answer 1 : " << (-b+sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
```

Same for Answer 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
cout << "Answer 1 : " << cout << (-b+sqrt(delta)) / (2*a);
```

Leave out the second `<< cout`.

You are also missing `{}` around the `else` branch code.